# How to add property annotation globally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations, model-binding

For preventing ASP.NET MVC from getting `null` for `string` properties, we can add this annotation to `string` properties:

```
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
```

What I'm looking for, is to this globally (in an entire project). So, I tried to create a custom model binder:

```
public class NotNullStringModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder {

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        if(controllerContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        if(bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");
        var providerResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if(providerResult == null)
            return string.Empty;
        var attemptedValue = providerResult.AttemptedValue;
        return attemptedValue ?? string.Empty;
    }

}
```

I have added this in `(global.asax).Application_Start()`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(string), new NotNullStringModelBinder());
```

But it doesn't work and I'm getting `null` for empty strings in all models. What I missed? Any idea please?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490210/asp-net-mvc-3-bind-string-property-as-string-empty-instead-of-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Kell seems all I needed to do was this:

```
public class NotNullStringModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder {

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false;
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice. I think I prefer the name EmptyStringModelBinder though :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here: [ASP.Net MVC 3 bind string property as string.Empty instead of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490210/asp-net-mvc-3-bind-string-property-as-string-empty-instead-of-null)

(The second answer in the question) It seems you have to bind to the property binding context, not the model binding context

Comment: Thanks. But not works. BUT, helped me to get the idea. See my answer please.